# ¿Por qué se eliminó la respuesta a "LARAVEL- Problema al leer hora desde BD"?

Tags: discusión

Me refiero a la respuesta de la pregunta
[LARAVEL- Problema al leer hora desde BD](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/601231/laravel-problema-al-leer-hora-desde-bd).

No encontré en internet un texto igual, de manera que no es por duplicada y tampoco se puede decir que sea de mala calidad.

Gbianchi, ¿algo se me escapa?

Comment: Si, esta copiada de una IA., como todas las respuestas que dio ese usuario...

Comment: y no se cerro.. las respuestas no se cierran.. las preguntas se cierran.. las respuestas se eliminan...

Comment: La respuesta de dicho usuario, como muchas otras de su cuenta, son respuestas que han sido generadas por IA. Si bien, la respuesta parece concisa o completa, va en contra de las políticas actuales del sitio. Sé que parece *rudo* borrar una respuesta así, pero más *rudo* me parece responder algo asumiendo la autoría de lo publicado, algo que éticamente está mal.

Comment: @gbianchi una consulta: Y porque no se han borrado las otras respuestas (a lo menos las que realizó a la misma hora)???? y porque no hay ban?

Comment: @Yussef esatn todas borradas, o me olvide alguna??? el usuario esta programado para ser eliminado...

Comment: Estas https://i.stack.imgur.com/omqRL.png

Comment: Uff de todas las razones que se me ocurrieron no había pensado en la IA. Así y todo era una buena respuesta. Gracias @gbianchi

Answer (score 6):

Según lo determinado aquí descrito:

[Moderation strike: Results of negotiations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391847/moderation-strike-results-of-negotiations)

Los Moderadores pueden intervenir en cuentas que se compruebe por heurística que están implementando cualquier IA para generar preguntas y respuestas.

Los usuarios afectados pueden solicitar investigación mediante el ticket a un CM aportando la evidencia que demuestre su autoría o justifique el proceso de redacción.

Los CM ahora pueden preguntar a los Moderadores sobre por qué tomaron XYZ decisión si así lo ven correcto, ya que los moderadores indican que no tienen ningún problema en dar esas explicaciones...

Todo lo anterior y el hecho de que impera la norma sobre propiedad intelectual para las publicaciones, está prohibido el uso de IA para generar contenido en el sitio.

***Amonestaciones que se le pueden dar a los usuarios:***

Desde un aviso por incumplimiento de la normas, hasta la más severa si continua realizando la actividad. Todo depende de la gravedad del asunto y la actitud del usuario, y las consideraciones que tome la moderación.

Comment: Mejor explicado imposible. Gracias